# Google Ads API with Google Apps Script no access token received

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, google-ads-api, google-developers-console

I am trying to use Google Ads on Google Apps Script using this [guide](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/examples/apps-scripts-execution). I created client id and client secret on Google Console's API & Services.

[image]

Not too sure if this configuration is correct but the account is linked to Google Apps Script as I have pagespeed insights as well and there are some requests on the dashboard. I added  `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` as the scope. Again not too sure if I should add Google Ads to the scope. Lastly, got my refresh token from [Google Auth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). When I run the script above I got the following error:

```
Error: No access token received: {
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "Unauthorized"
}
authenticate_   @ test.gs:120
withRefreshToken    @ test.gs:144
initializeOAuthClient   @ test.gs:28
```

Honestly not too sure what I am doing wrong here so any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

**Edit**
Codes:

```
//From Google Console API & Services
var CLIENT_ID = '"MY_CLIENT_ID';
var CLIENT_SECRET = 'MY_CLIENT_SECRET';
//From Google Authplayground
var REFRESH_TOKEN = 'REFRESH_TOKEN';
// Enter scopes which should match scopes in File > Project properties
// For this project, e.g.: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords";
// Script ID taken from 'File > Project Properties'
var SCRIPT_ID = 'MY_SCRIPT_ID';

var authUrlFetch;

// Call this function just once, to initialize the OAuth client.
function initializeOAuthClient() {
  if (typeof OAuth2 === 'undefined') {
    var libUrl = 'https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/examples/oauth20-library';
    throw Error('OAuth2 library not found. Please take a copy of the OAuth2 ' +
        'library from ' + libUrl + ' and append to the bottom of this script.');
  }
  var tokenUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
  authUrlFetch = OAuth2.withRefreshToken(tokenUrl, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,
    REFRESH_TOKEN, SCOPES);
}

/**
 * Execute a remote function.
 * @param {string} remoteFunctionName The name of the function to execute.
 * @param {Object[]} functionParams An array of JSON objects to pass to the
 *     remote function.
 * @return {?Object} The return value from the function.
 */
function executeRemoteFunction(remoteFunctionName, functionParams) {
  var apiParams = {
    'function': remoteFunctionName,
    'parameters': functionParams
  };
  var httpOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify(apiParams)
  };
  var url = 'https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/' + SCRIPT_ID + ':run';
  var response = authUrlFetch.fetch(url, httpOptions);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  // Retrieve the value that has been returned from the execution.
  if (data.error) {
    throw Error('There was an error: ' + response.getContentText());
  }
  return data.response.result;
}

// Paste in OAuth2 library here, from:
// https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/examples/oauth20-library
```

I have pasted the oauth2.0 library under the codes above.

**Edit 2** 
I fixed the part of `function initializeOAuthClient`. It now shows execution complete, but when I try to run `function executeRemoteFunction` I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined`. I am guessing I have to input `remoteFunctionName` and `functionParams` but where do I find them?

Comment: Can you provide your current script for replicating your issue?

Comment: @Tanaike I have added the codes